# Расположение многострочного текста по правую сторону с помощью CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Не получается отформатировать текст к правому краю, используя CSS Grid Layout.

Подскажите, как используя только возможности CSS grid layout (не используя `text-align: right`) отформатировать текст к правому краю?

Если строка недлинная то все ок, как только пишу длинное предложение, сбивается.

Пример и ссылка на codepen (33-я строка CSS)

```css
.form-label {
  justify-self: end;
  text-align: right; 
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/xarradex/pen/Wygxej)

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: #00beb2;
  --bg-color-form: #fef0d5;
  --color-white: #fef0d5;
  --dark: #1a5d63;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Markazi Text", serif;
}

header {
  place-self: center;
  color: var(--color-white);
}

.form-section {
  background-color: var(--bg-color-form);
  width: 960px;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  place-self: stretch center;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

.form-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-label {
  justify-self: end;
  text-align: right; /*  Fix problem with  * How likely is that you would... Dont justify text to right :( */
}

/* custom style */
.form-input textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  min-height: 4em;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.form-submit-button {
  display: grid;
}

.form-input-field {
  height: 2em;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid var(--bg-color);
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid var(--bg-color);
}

.form-submit {
  place-self: center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--color-white);
  border: 1px solid var(--dark);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 1em;
}


/* media */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .body {
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
  .form-section {
    background-color: var(--bg-color-form);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .form-section p {
    text-align: center;
    /*  fix p in center :(   */
  }
  .form-input-field {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .form-row {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    grid-gap: 0.5em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .form-input textarea {
    min-width: 90%;
  }
  .form-label {
    justify-self: start;
    text-align: left; /*  Fix problem with  * How likely is that you would... Dont justify text :( */
  }
  .survey-form {
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
</header>
<section class="form-section">
  <p id="description">Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp</p>
  <form action="" id="survey-form" class="survey-form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">* Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-input">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="form-input-field" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="email" id="email-label">* Email:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-input">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-input-field" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="number" id="number-label">* Age:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-input">
        <input type="number" name="age" id="number" placeholder="Your age" class="form-input-field" required min="1" max="125">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="dropdown">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-select">
        <select name="currentRole" id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
          <option value="none" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="job">Full time job</option>
          <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
          <option value="dontSay">Prefer not to say</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="recommendFCC">* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-radio" id="recommendFCC">
        <div class="form-radio-div">
          <input type="radio" id="definitely" name="recommend" value="definitetly" required>
          <label for="definitely">Definitely</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-radio-div">
          <input type="radio" id="maybe" name="recommend" value="maybe">
          <label for="maybe">Maybe</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-radio-div">
          <input type="radio" id="notSure" name="recommend" value="notSure">
          <label for="notSure">Not sure</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="mostLike">What do you like most in FCC:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-select">
        <select name="mostLike" id="mostLike" class="dropdown">
          <option value="none" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
          <option value="challenges">Challenges</option>
          <option value="project">Project</option>
          <option value="community">Community</option>
          <option value="openSource">Open source</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="preferences">Things that should be improved in the future</br>
(Check all that apply):</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-checkbox" id="preferences">
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="frontend" value="frontend">
          <label for="frontend">Front-end Projects</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="backend" value="backend">
          <label for="backend">Back-end Projects</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="dataVis" value="dataVis">
          <label for="dataVis">Data Visualization</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="challenges" value="challenges">
          <label for="challenges">Challenges</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="openSource" value="openSource">
          <label for="openSource">Open Source Community</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="gitter" value="gitter">
          <label for="gitter">Gitter help rooms</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="videos" value="videos">
          <label for="videos">Videos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="meetups" value="meetups">
          <label for="meetups">City Meetups</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="wiki" value="wiki">
          <label for="wiki">Wiki</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="forum" value="forum">
          <label for="forum">Forum</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox-item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shouldImprove" id="courses" value="courses">
          <label for="courses">Additional Courses</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-label">
        <label for="comment">Any Comments or Suggestions?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-input">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="20" rows="10" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter text here..." wrap="hard"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-submit-button">
      <button id="submit" type="submit" class="form-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Крайне сомневаюсь, что это у вас получится без `text-align`, так как CSS Grid выполнил здесь свой максимум: перенёс элемент на правую сторону — всё. Но дело в том, что многострочный элемент занимает всю ширину. А значит, как его ни располагай c помощью CSS Grid — расположение многострочного текста от этого не поменяется.